# Check failed: registry.count(type) == 0 (1 vs. 0) Layer type Split already registered

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I have created a python layer for data augmentation which worked well with digits but when I train the network using terminal command on ubuntu 14.04, I get this error:

```
I1130 16:29:56.155732 18230 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer aug_data
F1130 16:29:56.220578 18230 layer_factory.hpp:69] Check failed: registry.count(type) == 0 (1 vs. 0) Layer type Split already registered.
```

where `aug_data` is the custom python layer. I have made changes in configuration file to accept the python layer but I think there is something wrong with linking the layers that I could not fix. I cannot use DIGITS as my data is hyperspectral while the DIGITS accept either grayscale or RGB images.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show your source code

Comment: <a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/rmdnfnqt4nagg9d/aug_layer.py?dl=0">Augmentation layer file</a>

Comment: In prototxt file, I have added this layer as:                                            layer {
  name: "aug_data"
  type: "Python"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "data"
  python_param {
    module: "digits_python_layers"
    layer: "AugmentationLayer"
    param_str: "{\'num\': 21,\'isFlip\' : 1,\'isRotate\' : 1,\'stepRotate\' : 30}"
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

According to your prototxt file, you should be able to run "from digits_python_layers import AugmentationLayer". Does this work (from any directory)?

Old answer:

Your new layer should return something other than "Split" for its layer type (via its `type()` function).

Comment: Previously, it worked but after I rebuilt caffe for some reason, it gave this error. I rebuilt caffe one more time and now it cannot find this custom layer. The path of my new python layer is caffe/python.                                    Note: I enabled the python_layer check in config file while building caffe.

Comment: Thanks. I got it fixed. I was making mistake in adding the python module to the python path.